# How to change the color of clipping border display?

Tags: interface, customization, theme

Clipping border (<kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd>) makes a dark box around the selected area:

[image: gif]

Setting the background color to the same color as the box doesn't work if you have *Only render* enabled.

How to make the box transparent instead?

---

[Related BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?341580-ALT-B-Isolate-background-transparent).

Comment: @cegaton I don't think that's what the OP is asking at all.. (Though it's a bit unclear)

Comment: @David I think the OP is asking how to theme the clipping display box. Imo `theme` makes more sense here than `rendering`..

Comment: While there are a lot of colours you can change in a theme, not every colour is exposed in the theme settings. Some drawing is done by colours set within the code or as tints based on a set variation of a defined colour. I expect you will need to get a developer to create a patch to adjust this colour. As for only render - the world colour settings are shown in the background.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting for 'Clipping Border' now in newer version of Blender.
themes / preferences / 3dview / clipping border color option box.
The default color is a dark grey, and the setting for transparency is called 'A' for Alpha Value. The default Alpha is 1 which is Opaque, if you move the slider to '0' the View Clipping Background is Transparent!

Comment: And what should be put in?